# How do I target div class within a form?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to target `what` and `where`, as well as
`search`.

Here is my html:

```html
<div class="entry-content">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div class="entry-content">
  <div class="job_listings" data-location="" data-keywords="" data-show_filters="true" data-show_pagination="false" data-per_page="10" data-orderby="featured" data-order="DESC" data-categories="">
   <form class="job_filters">
    <div class="search_jobs">
     <div class="search_keywords">
      <label for="search_keywords">What?</label><br />
      <input id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" type="text" value="" placeholder="Chef, Cleaner, Manager" />
     </div>
     <div class="search_location">
      <label for="search_location">Where?</label><br />
      <input id="search_location" name="search_location" type="text" value="" placeholder="London, Berlin, Bristol" />
      <input name="filter_job_type[]" type="submit" value="search" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showing_jobs"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
     <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-a-job/">Post A Job</a>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <p><a class="load_more_jobs" style="display: none;" href="#"><strong>Load more listings</strong></a></p>
</div>
```

Tried everything including.

```
.entry-content {color: green;}
```

Interestingly,

```
. entry-content {background-color: green;}
```

works, but

```
.entry-content {color:  green! important;}
```

does nothing.

Comment: `.entry-content * {color: green! important;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following style to target all the labels inside `entry-content`. This works unless the style is not overrided by other styles

```
.entry-content label{
  color:green;
}
```

For specific labels, you can use,

```
.search_keywords label{
  color:green;
}

.search_location label{
  color:green;
}
```

**UPDATE**

For input fields like `chef,manager` etc you can use

```
.search_keywords input{
  //Your style here
}
```

or since you have id for the input field, use

```
#search_keywords{
  //Style here
}
```

and for the submit button `search`, you can use the following,

```
.search_location input[type=submit]{
  //style here
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  To target specific label would i use nth-child or nth-of-type etc?

Comment: In this case it's better to use the class of parent (like `search_keywords`) to target a specific label. So you could write `.entry-content .search_keywords label{color:green;}`

Comment: Ok.  What about `search`? Or the box for `chef, cleaner, manager`?

Comment: @user11364702 Glad to help. please upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can target by attribute and value:

```css
label[for="search_keywords"]{ /* what label*/
    background-color: red;
}

label[for="search_location"]{ /* where label */
    background-color: blue;
}

input[type="submit"]{ /* search button */
    background-color: green;
}
```

The color attribute refers to the text color, not the background colour.

Comment: It means they are being overwritten by more specific styles. Use the developer tools in your browser so which styles are conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Try [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
[for="search_keywords"],
[for="search_location"],
[name="filter_job_type[]"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="job_listings" data-location="" data-keywords="" data-show_filters="true" data-show_pagination="false" data-per_page="10" data-orderby="featured" data-order="DESC" data-categories="">
      <form class="job_filters">
        <div class="search_jobs">
          <div class="search_keywords">
            <label for="search_keywords">What?</label><br />
            <input id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" type="text" value="" placeholder="Chef, Cleaner, Manager" />
          </div>
          <div class="search_location">
            <label for="search_location">Where?</label><br />
            <input id="search_location" name="search_location" type="text" value="" placeholder="London, Berlin, Bristol" />
            <input name="filter_job_type[]" type="submit" value="search" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="showing_jobs"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-a-job/">Post A Job</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><a class="load_more_jobs" style="display: none;" href="#"><strong>Load more listings</strong></a></p>
</div>
```